# Does the following algebraic structure have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider a multiplicative abelian group $T$ and an additive abelian group $S$, along with the following axioms.

1. $t_1(t_2s) = (t_1t_2)s$ for $t_1,t_2 \in T$ and $s \in S$
2. $1s = s$, where $1$ denotes the identity in $T$ and $s \in S$
3. $t(s_1 + s_2) = ts_1 + ts_2$ for $t \in T$ and $s_1,s_2 \in S$

In other words, it is like a vector space with an abelian group in place of the scalar field.

Does this structure have a name? Are there any results known about this structure?

Comment: Isn't this just a group homomorphism from $T\times S$ to $S$?  Or am I missing something?  Also, if you haven't already, you may want to look up *modules*.

Comment: Modules require $T$ to be a ring, as far as I'm aware. Where exactly do you perceive a homomorphism?

Comment: $S$ and $T$ are abelian groups.  So far so good.  What you have added is an operation from $T\times S$ to $S$, akin to scalar multiplication in a vector space.  If you consider $T\times S$ to be the product group, then it seems to me that your axioms are just what is needed to show that this "scalar multiplication" operation is a group homomorphism.

Comment: There are such things as [$G$-modules where $G$ is a group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-module).  It's the same as considering $S$ as a module over the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$.

Answer (score 1):

It has a very well known name actually: $T$ acts via automorphisms on $S$.

As you can see by requiring your third condition (first two conditions for it to be action) every element of $T$ define an isomorphism from $S$ to $S$ which means you have an homomorphism from $T$ to $Aut(S)$.This is nothing but the essential thing to define semidirect product of $T$ and $S$. (of course, it is used in many places, many related results exist)

There is no need to require $S$ is abelian, we can define it in a general way.($S$ 's being abelian has no actual advantage to define the structure) To reach more information please read the chapter 3 of "Finite Group Theory by I.Martin Isaacs" or make research about "Split Extensions".